# Accessing breakpoints in included files using MVC framework (Xdebug mamp sublime tex)

Tags: php, mamp, sublimetext, xdebug

Just installed and using xdebug with sublime text in a mamp dev stack. All appears to be working fine, i have changed the project setting to open the browser to a specific url and all breakpoints work in the index file. However when placing breakpoints at any of the required files for example the home controller the do not work. How deep does x debug work ? does it only work on the highest loaded file instead of required / included files.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all, setting xdebug breakpoints in any included files should work fine. There must be another issue there.

Comment: Thats what i though any ideas ?

Comment: I'm afraid debugging that problem from the amount of information I have would be extremely difficult. How are you setting the breakpoints? Using xdebug_break(); ?

Comment: in sublime you have an xdebug menu that you can just add them to the selected line. Any specific info you need? 

I Have xdebug.collect_includes turned on.

Comment: Try putting xdebug_break(); directly in the files, see if that works?

Comment: yeah that seems to work fine although i don't like that its not very tidy, i suppose i can remove all lines when site is live.

Comment: I wouldn't leave them in there tbh, just add them in when you need them and then take them out afterwards. One thing that I have come across before is that when setting markers on lines to break on as you were before they have to be on lines that actually contain a line of code. Hopefully now you know xdebug is working you can find out what the issue is.